# Is there a rational point in a given open set such that the distancse from given rational points to it are all rational numbers on $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, rational-numbers, integer-lattices

On $R^2$ there is a nonempty open set $A$ and n rational points $a_1,...,a_n$. Is there a rational point $a$ in $A$ such that $\forall n\in\{1,..,n\},~|a-a_i|$ is a rational number.
My idea is to find a measuring method, in which the "length" of all rational points in unit circle is $0$ with universe set being $Q$ in unit circle, and then we can solve this question in a way similar to measure theory.

Comment: The question you ask is unknown, even for the four vertices of the unit square.  See the [four distance problem.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12097.pdf#:~:text=The%20four%2Ddistance%20problem%20is,that%20no%20such%20point%20exists.)  If you drop the condition that the points $a_i$ also be rational then the answer is negative, for measure theoretic reasons (see my now-deleted solution which missed the rationality condition on the starting points).

Comment: And [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2981v2.pdf) is a paper which gives explicit constructions of points which violate the $n-$rational distance problem, though it does not require the starting points to be rational (the arguments may or may not be relevant to your restricted question, but it is an interesting result).